# React native beacons manager - Background on android

Tags: react-native

First of all, I'm new on react native so the thing I'm asking may be well documented on the beacons manager library (https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager), but I can not figure it out.

I have a project using that library and it is working when the app is open (foreground), but I do not know how to make it search for beacons in the background. I'm working on Android but both Android and iOS answers are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do ranging when the app is in the background but you can do monitoring. You can use setBackgroundScanPeriod(period: number). I'm not sure if this applies to all kinds of beacons. For more... https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203356607-What-are-region-Monitoring-and-Ranging-

Comment: Humm ok! Thanks mate ;)